# AbstractAccountAuthenticator allow only 1 account

Tags: android, android-syncadapter, android-authenticator

I have implemented AbstractAccountAuthenticator as a requirement to use SyncAdapter hower my application is supporting only 1 account at a time.

When the user is trying to add another account via settings - Settings crash with an error that it stopped working.

I have seen some application e.g. LinkedIn, Facebook they somehow handle it differently a toast message is shown to the user with a statement that only 1 account is supported. How can I achieve this functionality?

This is my authenticator

```
class ApplicationAuthenticator(private val context: Context) : AbstractAccountAuthenticator(context) {

    // Editing properties is not supported
    @Throws(UnsupportedOperationException::class)
    override fun editProperties(response: AccountAuthenticatorResponse,
                                accountType: String): Bundle? {

        throw UnsupportedOperationException()
    }

    // Don't add additional accounts
    override fun addAccount(response: AccountAuthenticatorResponse, accountType: String,
                            authTokenType: String, features: Array<String>,
                            options: Bundle): Bundle? {

        return bundleOf(AccountManager.KEY_INTENT to null)
    }

    // Ignore attempts to confirm credentials
    @Throws(NetworkErrorException::class)
    override fun confirmCredentials(response: AccountAuthenticatorResponse, account: Account,
                                    options: Bundle): Bundle? {

        return null
    }

    // Getting an authentication token is not supported
    @Throws(NetworkErrorException::class, UnsupportedOperationException::class)
    override fun getAuthToken(response: AccountAuthenticatorResponse, account: Account,
                              authTokenType: String, loginOptions: Bundle): Bundle? {

        throw UnsupportedOperationException()
    }

    // Getting a label for the auth token is not supported
    override fun getAuthTokenLabel(authTokenType: String): String {
        return context.resources.getString(R.string.application_name)
    }

    // Updating user credentials is not supported
    override fun updateCredentials(response: AccountAuthenticatorResponse, account: Account,
                                   authTokenType: String, loginOptions: Bundle): Bundle? {

        return null
    }

    // Checking features for the account is not supported
    @Throws(NetworkErrorException::class)
    override fun hasFeatures(response: AccountAuthenticatorResponse, account: Account,
                             features: Array<String>): Bundle {

        return bundleOf(KEY_BOOLEAN_RESULT to false)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

When the user clicks the "Add Account" button, Android just calls the [`addAccount`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AbstractAccountAuthenticator#addAccount(android.accounts.AccountAuthenticatorResponse,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20android.os.Bundle)) method of your `ApplicationAuthenticator`. In return it expects either the account to be created, an Intent which launches the account setup or an error.

If you don't allow multiple accounts you have multiple options here:

- Return an error with code [ERROR_CODE_UNSUPPORTED_OPERATION](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager#ERROR_CODE_UNSUPPORTED_OPERATION). Although I've not tried that yet.
- Return your existing account as the result. At this point you can also show a `Toast`.

  To Return the existing account just let `addAccount` return a `Bundle` with the following keys and their respective values:

  > AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_NAME and AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_TYPE of the account that was added, or
- Return an Activity `Intent` which doesn't create an account but explains to the user that this is an unsupported/unnecessary operation. It's not a requirement that the Activity actually adds an account.

  This gives the best user experience IMO.

Comment: But how do I return the existing account as a result, do I need to implement AccountAuthenticatorActivity or can I just simple return that results directly from Authenticator?

Comment: I've updated the answer. Also make sure to remove `KEY_INTENT` from your bundle if you return the account instead.